# retrieve data from an array in Symofny

Tags: symfony, doctrine

i have a method that actually it returns an array

```
class PanierRepository extends EntityRepository
{
public function findAllOrderedByName($iduser)
{

return $this->getEntityManager()
->createQuery(
'SELECT p FROM techeventBundle:Panier p WHERE p.userid = :iduser'
)->setParameter('iduser',$iduser)
->getResult();
}
}
```

i thought that method will return an object 'Panier' but i noticed that when i call it in my controller it's returning an array (because i got this error : spl_object_hash() expects parameter 1 to be object, array given ) and i cannot retrieve it's data ,  this is the code :

```
            $panier = $this->getDoctrine()
                ->getManager()
                ->getRepository('techeventBundle:Panier')
                ->findAllOrderedByName($iduser);
//here i am trying to get data from the array but it's not working it's displaying an error Notice: Undefined offset: 0 //
           $id = panier[0];
```

i have 2 questions :
1. how can i change the return type of the 'indAllOrderedByName'method to an object  'Panier' ? 
2. if i cannot change the return type is there a solution to get the data from the returned array ?

Comment: hey guys i solved the problem , the getResult method returns an array of objects if you just need to return one object you can use getOneOrNullResult() or getSingleResult() they return one single object

Comment: Glad you could solve it. I will vote to close as the question no longer needs to be up.